# How to map a coordinate to another image(Open-CV)

Tags: python, opencv, coordinates

Hey guys im working on a simple eye tracking project i am planning on doing this by the following method:

1.find both pupils using Dlib and opencv thresholding which is working perfectly and providing the pupil center

2. I drew a rectangle by using the landmark coordinates of the eyes to draw a rectangle surrounding the eye such that the pupil is within this rectangle
3. I averaged the coordinates of the rectangles and pupils of both the eyes to get a rectangle at the centre of the nose or forehead region

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxVT9.png)

Now i need to map this averaged rectangle with the pupil coordinate the one in the green to the screen so that the boundaries of the rectangle acts as the screen boundaries and the pupil coordinates vaguely represent where i am looking at

Any idea how Thanks in Advance

heres how i tried to map it

```
import cv2
```

import numpy as np
from gaze_tracking import GazeTracking
from scipy.spatial import distance as dist

gaze = GazeTracking()
webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(2)

def map_to_smaller_bbox(sm_bbox_w, sm_bbox_h, lg_win_w, lg_win_h, avg_p_x, avg_p_y):

```
sm_height_delta = lg_win_h/sm_bbox_h
sm_width_delta = lg_win_w/sm_bbox_w

sm_scaled_x = round(avg_p_x/sm_width_delta)
sm_scaled_y = round(avg_p_y/sm_height_delta)

return [sm_scaled_x, sm_scaled_y]
```

def map_to_larger_bbox(sm_bbox_w, sm_bbox_h, win_w, win_h, sc_x, sc_y):

```
sc_height_delta = sm_bbox_h/win_h
sc_width_delta = sm_bbox_w/win_w

sc_win_x = round(sc_x/sc_width_delta)
sc_win_y = round(sc_y/sc_height_delta)

return [sc_win_x, sc_win_y]
```

def cam_frame_size(frame_cam):

```
cam_w, cam_h = gaze.get_frame_size()

return [cam_w, cam_h]
```

def screen_frame_size(frame_screen):

```
screen_w, screen_h = frame_screen.shape[:2]

return [screen_w, screen_h]
```

def get_gaze_coords(cam_frame):

```
left_pupil = gaze.pupil_left_coords()
right_pupil = gaze.pupil_right_coords()
coord_coll = gaze.eye_roi_bb()

if len(coord_coll) == 2:

    left_coords = coord_coll[0]
    right_coords = coord_coll[1]

    left_x1 = left_coords[0]
    left_x2 = left_coords[1]
    left_y1 = left_coords[2]
    left_y2 = left_coords[3]

    right_x1 = right_coords[0]
    right_x2 = right_coords[1]
    right_y1 = right_coords[2]
    right_y2 = right_coords[3]

    avg_x1 = int((left_x1 + right_x1)/2)
    avg_x2 = int((left_x2 + right_x2)/2)
    avg_y1 = int((left_y1 + right_y1)/2 - 5)
    avg_y2 = int((left_y2 + right_y2)/2 + 5)

    avg_bbox_w = int(dist.euclidean((avg_x1,avg_y1), (avg_x2, avg_y1)))
    avg_bbox_h = int(dist.euclidean((avg_x1,avg_y1), (avg_x1, avg_y2)))

    # avg_bbox_w_c = int((avg_x1+avg_x2)/2, (avg_y1+avg_y2)/2)
    # avg_bbox_h_c = int((avg))

    cam_size = cam_frame_size(cam_frame)

    cam_height_delta = cam_size[1]/avg_bbox_h
    cam_width_delta = cam_size[0]/avg_bbox_w

    screen_size = screen_frame_size(screen_frame)

    if left_pupil or right_pupil is not None:

        avg_pupil_x = int((right_pupil[0] + left_pupil[0])/2)
        avg_pupil_y = int((right_pupil[1] + left_pupil[1])/2)

        cv2.rectangle(cam_frame, (avg_x1,avg_y1), (avg_x2,avg_y2), (0, 255, 0), 1)
        cv2.rectangle(cam_frame, (right_x1,right_y1-5), (right_x2,right_y2+5), (0, 0, 255), 1)
        cv2.rectangle(cam_frame, (left_x1,left_y1-5), (left_x2,left_y2+5), (0, 0, 255), 1)

        # sm_sc_coords = map_to_smaller_bbox(avg_bbox_w, avg_bbox_h,
        #                     cam_size[0], cam_size[1], avg_pupil_x,avg_pupil_y)



        # lg_sc_coords = map_to_larger_bbox(avg_bbox_w, avg_bbox_h,
        #         screen_size[0], screen_size[1], sm_sc_coords[0], sm_sc_coords[1])

        return (avg_pupil_x, avg_pupil_y)
```

while True:
# We get a new frame from the webcam
ret, cam_frame = webcam.read()

```
if not ret:

    print("Couldn't get Video Source")
    break

# We send this frame to GazeTracking to analyze it
gaze.refresh(cam_frame)

cam_frame = gaze.annotated_frame()
screen_frame = np.zeros((1366, 768, 3), np.uint8)
# text = ""

# if gaze.is_blinking():
#     text = "Blinking"
# elif gaze.is_right():
#     text = "Looking right"
# elif gaze.is_left():
#     text = "Looking left"
# elif gaze.is_center():
#     text = "Looking center"

# cv2.putText(frame, text, (90, 60), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 0.5, (147, 58, 31), 1)

# left_pupil = gaze.pupil_left_coords()
# right_pupil = gaze.pupil_right_coords()

# if (left_pupil or right_pupil) != None :
#     avg_center_coords = (int((left_pupil[0] + right_pupil[0])/2), int((left_pupil[1] + right_pupil[1])/2))
#     cv2.putText(frame, "Avg: " + str(avg_center_coords), (90, 200), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 0.5, (147, 58, 31), 1)

# cv2.putText(frame, "Left pupil:  " + str(left_pupil), (90, 130), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 0.5, (147, 58, 31), 1)
# cv2.putText(frame, "Right pupil: " + str(right_pupil), (90, 165), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 0.5, (147, 58, 31), 1)


# coord_coll = gaze.eye_roi_bb()

# if len(coord_coll) == 2:

#     left_coords = coord_coll[0]
#     right_coords = coord_coll[1]

#     left_x1 = left_coords[0]
#     left_x2 = left_coords[1]
#     left_y1 = left_coords[2]
#     left_y2 = left_coords[3]

#     right_x1 = right_coords[0]
#     right_x2 = right_coords[1]
#     right_y1 = right_coords[2]
#     right_y2 = right_coords[3]

#     avg_x1 = int((left_x1 + right_x1)/2)
#     avg_x2 = int((left_x2 + right_x2)/2)
#     avg_y1 = int((left_y1 + right_y1)/2 - 5)
#     avg_y2 = int((left_y2 + right_y2)/2 + 5)

    # cv2.rectangle(frame, (avg_x1,avg_y1), (avg_x2,avg_y2), (0, 255, 0), 1)
    # cv2.rectangle(frame, (right_x1,right_y1-5), (right_x2,right_y2+5), (0, 0, 255), 1)

    # left_bbox_width = int((left_x2 - left_x1) + 1)
    # left_bbox_height = int((left_y2 - left_y1) + 1)

    # right_bbox_width = int((right_x2 - right_x1) + 1)
    # right_bbox_height = int((right_y2 - right_y1) + 1)

    # print((left_bbox_width, left_bbox_height), (right_bbox_width, right_bbox_height))

    # left_bbox_w = int(dist.euclidean((left_x1,left_y1),(left_x2,left_y2)))
    # left_bbox_h = int(dist.euclidean((left_x1,left_y2),(left_x1,left_y1)))
    # right_bbox_w = int(dist.euclidean((right_x1,right_y1),(right_x2,right_y2)))
    # right_bbox_w = int(dist.euclidean((right_x1,right_y2),(right_x1,right_y1)))

    # avg_bbox_w = int(dist.euclidean((avg_x1,avg_y1), (avg_x2, avg_y1)))
    # avg_bbox_h = int(dist.euclidean((avg_x1,avg_y1), (avg_x1, avg_y2)))
    
    # print(avg_bbox_w, avg_bbox_h)

    # width, height = gaze.get_frame_size()
    # width, height = width, height

    # height_delta = height/avg_bbox_h
    # width_delta = width/avg_bbox_w

    # if right_pupil is not None:

    #     scaled_x1 = round(right_pupil[0]*height_delta)

    # print(width_delta, height_delta)

    # cv2.rectangle(frame, (scaled_x1, scaled_x2), (scaled_y1, scaled_y2), (0,0,255), 1)

    # print(scaled_x1, scaled_x2, scaled_y1, scaled_y2)
    
    # if left_pupil or right_pupil is not None:

    #     avg_pupil_x = int((right_pupil[0] + left_pupil[0])/2)
    #     avg_pupil_y = int((right_pupil[1] + left_pupil[1])/2)

    #     sm_sc_coords = map_to_smaller_bbox(avg_bbox_w, avg_bbox_h,
    #                         width, height, avg_pupil_x,avg_pupil_y)

    #     # print(sm_sc_coords[0], sm_sc_coords[1])

    #     # cv2.rectangle(frame, (sm_sc_coords[2], sm_sc_coords[4]), (sm_sc_coords[3], sm_sc_coords[5]), (0,0,255), 1)

    #     lg_sc_coords = map_to_larger_bbox(avg_bbox_w, avg_bbox_h,
                # width, height, sm_sc_coords[0], sm_sc_coords[1])

        # cv2.rectangle(frame, (lg_sc_coords[2], lg_sc_coords[4]), (lg_sc_coords[3], lg_sc_coords[5]), (0,0,255), 1)

        # print(lg_sc_coords[0], lg_sc_coords[1])

        # scaled_x = round(avg_pupil_x*width_delta)
        # scaled_y = round(avg_pupil_y*height_delta)

        # print(avg_pupil_x, avg_pupil_y, scaled_x, scaled_y)

p_xy = get_gaze_coords(cam_frame)

print(p_xy)

# if p_xy is not None:

#     # print(p_xy)

#     screen_frame = cv2.circle(screen_frame, (p_xy[0], p_xy[1]), 10, (0, 255, 0), 1)
        # cv2.line(frame, (left_pupil[0], left_pupil[1]), (lg_sc_coords[0], lg_sc_coords[1]), (0,0,255), 1) 
        # cv2.line(frame, (right_pupil[0], right_pupil[1]), (lg_sc_coords[0], lg_sc_coords[1]), (0,0,255), 1) 

        # print(lg_sc_coords[2], lg_sc_coords[4], lg_sc_coords[3], lg_sc_coords[5])

# cv2.namedWindow('Demo',cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
# cv2.namedWindow('gaze',cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

cv2.imshow("Demo", cam_frame)
# cv2.imshow("gaze", screen_frame)

if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
    break
```

Comment: It's not so simple ) 
You can get some ideas here: https://github.com/hugochan/Eye-Tracker
And check github topics: https://github.com/topics/gaze-tracking

Comment: im actually using antoinelames code as a base to work on and yeah its been a pain since im pretty new to programming. but it think it might perform good if we got it to work nvm about the accuracy .it would be able to provide a vage gaze estimation point though right?

PS: thanks for responding